# Custom Output In Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am trying to connect a heatmap and dendrogram rendered in R, depending on user input via Shiny, to the InCHlib JavaScript library. In order to update the heatmap when input changes I need to write a custom output binding. I've studied the tutorial and a bunch of examples I found on the web but somehow I'm not getting any output.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
soucre("HeatMapBinding.R")
shinyUI(
   fluidPage(
   ...
       mainPanel(           
           heatMapOutput("heatmap")
       )        
   )
)
```

server.R

```
source("InCHlibUtils.R")
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
output$heatmap <- reactive({

    if(input$get == 0)
        return()

    isolate({
        data <- retrieveData()
        hc.row <- hclust(dist(data), input$cluster.method)
        hc.col <- hclust(dist(t(data)), input$cluster.method)
        map <- InCHlib(hc.row, hc.col, data)})   # Nested List, JSON ready
        # How I previously wrote the data to a file in the correct JSON format
        # for the javascript library to pick up later. This was of course not dynamic
        # writeLines(toJSON(map), "heatmap.json")
    })
})
```

HeatMapBinding.R

```
library(shiny)
heatMapOutput <- function(inputId, width="1000px", height="1200px") {
    style <- sprintf("width: %s; height: %s;", validateCssUnit(width), validateCssUnit(height))

    tagList(
        singleton(tags$head(
                        tags$script(src="scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"),
                        tags$script(src="scripts/kinetic-v5.0.0.min.js"),
                        tags$script(src="scripts/inchlib-1.0.0.js"),
                        tags$script(src="scripts/heatmap.js")
                )),
        div(id=inputId, class="InCHlib-heatmap", style=style,
                tag("div", list())
        )
    )
}
```

heatmap.js

```
(function() {
    var binding = new Shiny.OutputBinding();

    binding.find = function(scope) {
        return $(scope).find(".InCHlib-heatmap");
    };

    binding.renderValue = function(el, data) {
       var $el = $(el);

       // Original javascript that worked stand alone
       $(document).ready(function() { //run when the whole page is loaded
           window.inchlib = new InCHlib({ //instantiate InCHlib
               target: "inchlib", //ID of a target HTML element
               metadata: false, //turn off the metadata 
               max_height: 1200, //set maximum height of visualization in pixels
               width: 1000, //set width of visualization in pixels
               heatmap_colors: "Greens", //set color scale for clustered data
               metadata_colors: "Reds", //set color scale for metadata
           });
           // originaly a file was loaded, now i want to load the data(frame)
           // inchlib.read_data_from_file(heatmap.json)  //read input json file
           if(data != null){
               inchlib.read_data(data);                  //read input json data?
               inchlib.draw();                           //draw cluster heatmap
           }
       };  
   };  

  //Tell Shiny about our new output binding 
  Shiny.outputBindings.register(binding, "shinyjsexamples.InCHlib-heatmap");

})();
```

If I'm not mistaken I don't need a renderHeatMap function in server.R to be defined because my data is already JSON ready?

When I'm debugging my JavaScript heatmap.js the renderValue function gets called right after the page is loaded, when there's no data available. And that's the only time the function gets called. I know the R side of things work up until the output$heatmap (If I do write that json file, that file looks fine). And If I debug my JavaScript I see the right data getting loaded in.

I don't feel like I thoroughly understand the custom output binding mechanism. So it would be a big help if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a working solution:

First of all if your data is JSON ready like mentioned above, you indeed have no need for a renderHeatMap sort of function in the HeatMapBinding.R.

The problem above is more of an HTML issue:

In the heatmap.js we initialize our InCHlib heatmap as follows:

```
   window.inchlib = new InCHlib({ //instantiate InCHlib
               target: "inchlib", //ID of a target HTML element
               metadata: false, //turn off the metadata 
               max_height: 1200, //set maximum height of visualization in pixels
               width: 1000, //set width of visualization in pixels
               heatmap_colors: "Greens", //set color scale for clustered data
               metadata_colors: "Reds", //set color scale for metadata
           });
```

the target element embodies the id of the HTML element it wil get displayed in. But in my heatMapOutput in HeatMapBinding.R I get an inputId argument of "heatmap" because my server.R catches an output$heatmap variable, this id also gets used in my ui.R code: heatMapOutput("heatmap").

Just changing that target element in heatmap.js solves the issue.

But this clearly is somewhat of a workaround and not a general solution. Should I make a renderHeatMap sort of function in the HeatMapBinding.R to pass along the inputId (how would I be able to access that id from within that function?) and use it when initializing my InCHlib heatmap or is this rather an issue I should solve in the JavaScript of the InCHlib?